# Best practice to use @PreAuthorize

Tags: java, spring-security, architecture, spring-boot

I have a service class with secured methods (`@PreAuthorize`, Spring Security).

Is Its bad practice coding?

Maybe should I use this annotation `@PreAuthorize` only in my controller class (`@Controller` or `@RestController`)

Comment: It depends. How your security checks are done, if they are only role based you could argue, if they are more complex (including expressions for instance) they might be on the service layer. Your service layer is the actual boundary for transactions and as well as security, everything else is integration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, ideally, this type of authorization checks should be done at Controller or the first request handler step (like RestController which you mentioned). It makes more sense to put `@PreAuthorize` annotation on Controller methods as request will not be forwarded to Service layer and unnecessary code (code which is there in controller method) will not be executed if correct role is not found.

BUT

If you have and application where service classes is being used by multiple controllers then you can have `@PreAuthorize` annotation on Service layer. If tomorrow someone create a new controller(and forgets to use correct authorization checks) and use the existing service class then your application will handle the authorization correctly using service layer authorization.

Comment: I tried putting @PreAuthorize on the Service class and got `An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext`

Answer (score 0):

Normally I use @PreAuthorize/@PostAuthorize on Service Layer and `<sec:intercept-url` or `javaconfig` to check the roles for Controllers/Urls.

If you have to check something inside the data/object(like if user has permission for changing data from one specific company) you should check in the Service Layer.